# Incrementing loops the right way for a triple nested loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, break

I am writing a triple nested loop, as you can see below, but having trouble understanding how to increment each one of them separately or one by one.

I have figured how to increment i before I get to the j and k loop by using next but I am getting lost after that

What do I do if I want to increment just k and not j or vice versa?

What if I want to increment both j and k but not i ?

What if I want to increment i once Im in the middle of the j and k loops?

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
        if(is.na(df[i,6]) == TRUE){
          score[i] = 0
          next
        }
        d = df[i, 3:32] == df[i-1, 3:32]
        if(all(d) == TRUE){
          score[i] = 0
          next
        }
        for(j in h){
          for(k in h)
        bidside = data.frame(DateTime=DateTime, Seq=Seq, BP1=BP1, BQ1=BQ1, BP2=BP2, BQ2=BQ2, BP3=BP3, BQ3=BQ3, BP4=BP4, BQ4=BQ4, BP5=BP5, BQ5=BQ5)
        askside = data.frame(DateTime=DateTime, Seq=Seq, AP1=AP1, AQ1=AQ1, AP2=AP2, AQ2=AQ2, AP3=AP3, AQ3=AQ3, AP4=AP4, AQ4=AQ4, AP5=AP5, AQ5=AQ5)
        x = askside[i, 3:12] == askside[i-1, 3:12]
        if(all(x) == TRUE){
          if(bidside[i,j] == bidside[i-1,k)
        }
      }
```

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any more info.

EDIT: Sample Data

```
> head(df, 50)
       DateTime Seq   BP1 BQ1 BO1   AP1 AQ1 AO1   BP2 BQ2 BO2   AP2 AQ2 AO2   BP3 BQ3 BO3   AP3 AQ3 AO3   BP4 BQ4 BO4   AP4 AQ4 AO4   BP5 BQ5 BO5   AP5 AQ5 AO5
1  1.442375e+18   1     0   0   0 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
2  1.442375e+18   2 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
3  1.442375e+18   3 70730   1   1 72830   1   1 70185   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
4  1.442375e+18   4 70730   1   1 72830   1   1 70340   1   1     0   0   0 70185   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
5  1.442375e+18   5 70730   1   1 72830   1   1 70340   1   1     0   0   0 70285   1   1     0   0   0 70185   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
6  1.442375e+18   6 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0 70285   1   1     0   0   0 70185   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
7  1.442375e+18   7 70735   2   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0 70285   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
8  1.442375e+18   8 70735   3   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
9  1.442375e+18   9 70905   1   1 72830   1   1 70735   3   1     0   0   0 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
10 1.442375e+18  10 70910   1   1 72830   1   1 70905   1   1     0   0   0 70735   2   1     0   0   0 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
11 1.442375e+18  11 70910   2   1 72830   1   1 70905   1   1     0   0   0 70735   1   1     0   0   0 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
12 1.442375e+18  12 70910   2   1 72535   4   1 70905   1   1 72830   1   1 70735   1   1     0   0   0 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
13 1.442375e+18  13 70910   2   1 72430   1   1 70905   1   1 72535   4   1 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
14 1.442375e+18  14 70910   2   1 72370   1   1 70905   1   1 72430   1   1 70735   1   1 72535   4   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0
15 1.442375e+18  15 70910   2   1 72370   1   1 70905   1   1 72410   1   1 70735   1   1 72430   1   1 70730   1   1 72535   4   1     0   0   0 72830   1   1
16 1.442375e+18  16 70910   2   1 72365   4   1 70905   1   1 72370   1   1 70735   1   1 72410   1   1 70730   1   1 72430   1   1     0   0   0 72830   1   1
17 1.442375e+18  17 70910   2   1 72360   1   1 70905   1   1 72365   4   1 70735   1   1 72410   1   1 70730   1   1 72430   1   1     0   0   0 72830   1   1
18 1.442375e+18  18 70910   2   1 72360   2   1 70905   1   1 72365   4   1 70735   1   1 72430   1   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0
19 1.442375e+18  19 70910   2   1 72355   4   1 70905   1   1 72360   2   1 70735   1   1 72430   1   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0
20 1.442375e+18  20 70910   2   1 72355   4   1 70905   1   1 72360   3   1 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
21 1.442375e+18  21 70910   2   1 72350   1   1 70905   1   1 72355   4   1 70735   1   1 72360   2   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0
22 1.442375e+18  22 70910   2   1 72350   2   1 70905   1   1 72355   4   1 70735   1   1 72360   1   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0
23 1.442375e+18  23 70910   2   1 72350   3   1 70905   1   1 72355   4   1 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
24 1.442375e+18  24 70910   2   1 72345   4   1 70905   1   1 72350   3   1 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
25 1.442375e+18  25 70910   2   1 72340   1   1 70905   1   1 72345   4   1 70735   1   1 72350   2   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0
26 1.442375e+18  26 70910   2   1 72340   2   1 70905   1   1 72345   4   1 70735   1   1 72350   1   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0
27 1.442375e+18  27 70910   2   1 72340   3   1 70905   1   1 72345   4   1 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0
28 1.442375e+18  28 70910   2   1 72340   3   1 70905   1   1 72345   4   1 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0 69880  10   1     0   0   0
29 1.442375e+18  29 70910   2   1 72340   3   1 70905   1   1 72345   4   1 70735   1   1 72830   1   1 70730   1   1     0   0   0 69880  10   1     0   0   0
30 1.442375e+18  30 70910   3   1 72340   3   1 70905   1   1 72345   4   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0 69790  10   1     0   0   0
31 1.442375e+18  31 70910   2   1 72340   3   1 70905   1   1 72345   4   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1 70185   1   1     0   0   0 69880  10   1     0   0   0
32 1.442375e+18  32 70910   2   1 72295   4   1 70905   1   1 72340   3   1 70730   1   1 72830   1   1 70185   1   1     0   0   0 69880  10   1     0   0   0
33 1.442375e+18  33 70910   2   1 72290   1   1 70905   1   1 72295   4   1 70730   1   1 72340   2   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
34 1.442375e+18  34 70910   2   1 72290   2   1 70905   1   1 72295   4   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
35 1.442375e+18  35 70910   2   1 72285   4   1 70905   1   1 72290   2   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
36 1.442375e+18  36 70910   2   1 72280   1   1 70905   1   1 72285   4   1 70730   1   1 72290   1   1 70185   1   1 72340   1   1 69880  10   1 72830   1   1
37 1.442375e+18  37 70910   2   1 72280   2   1 70905   1   1 72285   4   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
38 1.442375e+18  38 70910   2   1 72275   4   1 70905   1   1 72280   2   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
39 1.442375e+18  39 70910   2   1 72270   1   1 70905   1   1 72275   4   1 70730   1   1 72280   1   1 70185   1   1 72340   1   1 69880  10   1 72830   1   1
40 1.442375e+18  40 70910   2   1 72270   2   1 70905   1   1 72275   4   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
41 1.442375e+18  41 70910   2   1 72265   4   1 70905   1   1 72270   2   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
42 1.442375e+18  42 70910   2   1 72260   1   1 70905   1   1 72265   4   1 70730   1   1 72270   1   1 70185   1   1 72340   1   1 69880  10   1 72830   1   1
43 1.442375e+18  43 70910   2   1 72260   2   1 70905   1   1 72265   4   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
44 1.442375e+18  44 70910   2   1 72255   4   1 70905   1   1 72260   2   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
45 1.442375e+18  45 70910   2   1 72250   1   1 70905   1   1 72255   4   1 70730   1   1 72260   1   1 70185   1   1 72340   1   1 69880  10   1 72830   1   1
46 1.442375e+18  46 70910   2   1 72250   2   1 70905   1   1 72255   4   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
47 1.442375e+18  47 70910   2   1 72245   4   1 70905   1   1 72250   2   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
48 1.442375e+18  48 70910   2   1 72240   1   1 70905   1   1 72245   4   1 70730   1   1 72250   1   1 70185   1   1 72340   1   1 69880  10   1 72830   1   1
49 1.442375e+18  49 70910   2   1 72240   2   1 70905   1   1 72245   4   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
50 1.442375e+18  50 70910   2   1 72235   4   1 70905   1   1 72240   2   1 70730   1   1 72340   1   1 70185   1   1 72830   1   1 69880  10   1     0   0   0
```

Basically, I am trying to compare each row(i) to the one before(i-1) column by column. So if a value in (i) doesn't match a value in (i-1), I want to move either j or k depending on whether the value increased or decreased. And then once it reaches the end of either j or k, increment i and start at the top.

In case you have a quant background. Im trying to capture neworders/cancellations and modifications of an orderbook. That might help in understanding the question a little bit. Every row only has one change from the one from the before and I need to figure out what the change is.

Comment: Do you have some sample data for us? This would help us understanding your question a bit easier.

Comment: Im still slightly confused by your question, but from what I have read, you want to compare each row to the one above it, and then you want to go across your entire dataframe. Im confused exactly what j and k are doing. this line `if(bidside[i,j] == bidside[i-1,k)` will not do anything, so I am not sure what you are attempting to do. Can you please explain a little more?

Comment: Why do you say it wont do anything? Is my logic wrong there?

Comment: j is gonna loop over the columns of the row I am currently looking at, which is i 
k is gonna loop over the columns of the row Im comparing i to, which is i-1

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming i = 1:3, j = 1:3, k= 1:2

# Your values would increment in the order below:
   i       j        k
   1       1        1
   1       1        2
   1       2        1
   1       2        2
   1       3        1
   1       3        2
   2       1        1
   2       1        2
   2       2        1
   2       2        2
   2       3        1
   2       3        2
   3       1        1
   3       1        2
   3       2        1
   3       2        2
   3       3        1
   3       3        2
```

First your k loop should be completed for the current i and j, then j loop would increment and then i loop. 
Inside loops are incremented first, and then the outer and then the outermost.

Comment: Okay, so then my logic is completely wrong because that's not what I want it to do. I want j and k to increment simultaneously for an equality(==) condition, k to increment for a greater (>) than condition and j to increment for a less (<) than condition. And once j and k have been completed, I want to increment i... Is this possible? Any suggestions on how I should structure it then?